# How to establish connection for mining testnet blocks on newly created altcoin

Tags: network, testnet, altcoin

I was trying to clone an altcoin for educational purposes. I am total newby and I've got some plans to implement different PoW and continue working on cryto-currencies.

I followed the [cloning guide by Shakezula](http://devtome.com/doku.php?id=scrypt_altcoin_cloning_guide&rev=1391981820).

I followed all steps in the guide, however I am losing the main point: thus I am unable to connect machines to start mining. Can anyone please explain what I am doing incorrectly? I am struggling with this and am really looking forward to understand.

What I do not understand is the point on port forwarding from Shakezula's guide:

> Side note: because I use a VPS for this, I don't really need to worry
>   about port forwarding at that end. On the home PC, you will want to
>   forward the port you chose for P2Pport in the cut and paste section to
>   the PC you're using. For this example, that is port 55884.

What does it mean?  Does it mean that I should add this port in .conf file of the machines?

My case:

- I am trying to connect compiled coins on two VM machines: VM1 with IP `192.168.122.121` & VM2 with IP `192.168.122.158` (they are able to ping each other)
- In my conf files I only put rpc username/password
- On VM1 I do `./barcoin -testnet -connect=192.168.122.158 &`
- On VM2 I do `./barcoin -testnet -connect=192.168.122.121 &`

In .barcoin/testnet3/debug.log I get the following:

```
ThreadSocketHandler started connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
Flushed 0 addresses to peers.dat 42ms
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused}
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
```

I added this port 55884 to conf file of one of the machines and getting the same error.

Then I added command `connect=192.168.122.121:55884` to one of the conf files and started getting this:

```
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121:55884 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 192.168.122.121 lastseen=0.0hrs connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
```

Please help me with this one.
Thank you very much!

Comment: So your question is "what is port forwarding", right? Did you try punching "port forwarding" into your favorite search engine or going to `portforward.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am glad to say I found a solution. It is quite trivial:

 The main PC, the main node, should be listening for others, therefore you need to add a command:

```
listen=1
```

In addition, I would suggest you to add following commands as well, but for all nodes:

```
testnet=1
testnet_config=1
```

Good luck everyone.